# IOS XMLParsing HTML tags Come in Description field

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

I am working on XMLparsing and i am successfully get title and other description but when i get description i am also getting html and etc in description field , like this. How to remove this from my description.
Here i attached my xml parsing methods.

I tried to added image lots of time but don't know i am not able to add image , so i have added link here .

[image: Fixed Link]

Here is XML Link from which i also get HTML tag.

[http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/world](https://news.yahoo.com/rss/world)

```
//MainViewcontroller.h File
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDataSource,NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
NSXMLParser *parser;
NSMutableArray *feeds;
NSMutableDictionary *item;
NSMutableString *title;
NSMutableString *link;
NSString *element;
NSMutableString *CurrentAttribute;
NSMutableString *imageurlstring;
UIImage *image;
    NSMutableString *Description;

NSMutableArray *arrImage;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;

 //MainViewController.m File

 -(void)CallForWebService:(NSURL *)url
{
 parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

 [parser setDelegate:self];
 arrImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 imageurlstring = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
 [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
 [parser parse];
 //[self.tableview reloadData];

  NSLog(@"%@",parser);
}




  - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

element = elementName;

if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"])
{
    item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    imageurlstring=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    Description=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];


}
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail"]) {
    NSLog(@"thumbnails media:thumbnail: %@", attributeDict);
    imageurlstring = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
}
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"])
{
    [title appendString:string];
} else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"])
{
    [link appendString:string];
}
else if ([element isEqualToString:@"media:content"])
{
    [imageurlstring appendString:string];

}
 else if ([element isEqualToString:@"description"])
{
    [Description appendString:string];

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])
{
    [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];
    [item setObject:imageurlstring forKey:@"media:content"];
    [item setObject:Description forKey:@"description"];

    [feeds addObject:[item copy]]; 
   //feed = nsarray and item = dictionaryname

}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
{

[self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Your image is not showing, and it would help if we see the input XML as well.

Comment: If you are getting html tags, then you have to use nsstring classes to remove those tags.

Comment: @Glorfindel sorry i have added image but don't know not able to see. i have Edited question please check. and also link.

Comment: @Rajatp can you explain beat in detail where i have to use nsstring classes and how to use it ?

Comment: You may get help from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226634/converting-html-text-into-plain-text-using-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very nice project on github [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser).Please check this project, it has some methods

```
- (NSString *)stringByStrippingTags;
- (NSString *)stringWithNewLinesAsBRs;
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace;
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;
```

And you can use the method in your project like this

```
NSString *summary = [[[myHtmlStringToDecode stringByStrippingTags] stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace] stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];
```

For parsing images please check [MWFeedParser - RSS with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254500/mwfeedparser-rss-with-images-xcode)

Comment: thanks for the replay. how to add image i havn't found anything regarding image.\

Comment: check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: he he . i want to know regarding MWFeedParse. how to parse image and add it in uitableview. thanks

Comment: i am suggesting you MWFeedParser for decoding the html tags, by the way are you getting the link of image in your XML.

Comment: If you are getting the link of image then please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315539/how-to-include-sdwebimage-framework

Comment: without using mwfeed i get imagelink but with using this mwfeed i havn't seen about image anywhere.

Comment: i converted my whole project with mwparser now please don't said it dosn't support image parsing. ):

Comment: i checked this url but where i have to add object for key ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87651/discussion-between-rajatp-and-badal-shah).